# Confusión con los punteros inteligentes

Tags: c++, punteros-inteligentes

Poseo una confusión con esto de los punteros inteligentes, aunque leyendo la teoría puedo identificar *más o menos* las diferencias entre `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` y `weak_ptr` aún no logro dominarlas.

Tengo un proyecto que lo estoy realizando por capas, en la capa mas baja la cuál consulta al motor de base de datos, estoy utilizando un `std::vector` para guardar los valores retornados por la consulta y devolverlos por las diferentes capas hasta el usuario, el vector o más bien "matrix" es el siguiente:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> nombreVector;
```

Utilizo vectores porque yo se cuantas filas y columnas me retorno la consulta, así que puedo inicializar el tamaño del vector de manera fija sin tener que redefinirlo.

La función que consulta posee esta forma:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> RetornoConsulta;
const RetornoConsulta* consultar_tabla_x(int codigoTabla)
{
    RetornoConsulta *retorno = nullptr;

    try
    {
        retorno = extraer_datos_consulta(codigoTabla);
    }
    catch(std::exception &ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

No deseo entrar mucho en detalles, porque esta función esta divida por muchísimas funciones más, pero esto es una idea general, *estaba* utilizando un puntero en bruto, porque tengo toda la intención de que la memoria del vector "exista" aún fuera del ámbito de la función y no quiero mandar el vector por valor, porque esta función, esta encapsulada en otra función de la capa superior y esa a su vez esta encapsulada en otra, imagina mandando por valor un vector de 1.000 o más registros, siendo copiados innecesariamente una y otra vez.

Leyendo sobre las excepciones me tope que esta manera de utilizar punteros en bruto puede ocasionar una fuga de memoria cuando se lance una excepción inesperada y se recomienda profundamente los punteros inteligentes.

Aquí entra mi confusión, deseo utilizar ese vector con un puntero inteligente, algo como `unique_ptr<RetornoConsulta> ptrConsulta` y que mi función retorne eso.

Se que mandar un `unique_ptr` por referencia no posee chiste(o eso he leído), pero quiero que mi función retorne la *referencia* del vector la cual esta encapsulada por `unique_ptr`.

¿Basta con solo retornar `unique_ptr` por valor? ya que el valor de este, es la referencia del vector... algo como:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> RetornoConsulta;
unique_ptr<RetornoConsulta> consultar_tabla_x(int codigoTabla)
{
    unique_ptr<RetornoConsulta> ptrRetorno;

    try
    {
        //unique_ptr fue inicializado dentro con make_unique<RetornoConsulta>(nFilas)
        //Y regresado por valor de la misma forma que esta función la retorna
        ptrRetorno = extraer_datos_consulta(codigoTabla));            
    }
    catch(std::exception &ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return ptrRetorno;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No deseo entrar mucho en detalles, porque esta función esta divida por muchísimas funciones más, pero esto es una idea general, estaba utilizando un puntero en bruto, porque tengo toda la intención de que la memoria del vector "exista" aún fuera del ámbito de la función y no quiero mandar el vector por valor, porque esta función, esta encapsulada en otra función de la capa superior y esa a su vez esta encapsulada en otra, imagina mandando por valor un vector de 1.000 o más registros, siendo copiados innecesariamente una y otra vez.

Para solucionar este problema no es necesario recurrir a punteros inteligentes:

(Ejemplo que parte del código expuesto por [@PaperBirdMaster](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/239708/463))

```
#include <iostream>

#define PF std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

struct S
{
    S() { PF; }
    S(const S &) { PF; }
    S(S &&) { PF; }
    ~S(){ PF; }
};

template<int R>
S miFunc()
{
  S s = miFunc<R-1>();
  PF;
  return s;
}

template<>
S miFunc<0>()
{
  S s;
  PF;
  return s;
}

int main()
{
  S s = miFunc<10>();
  PF;
}
```

La plantilla `miFunc` lo que hace es llamarse de forma recursiva un número de veces dado (no me gusta repetir código).

El programa en sí llama de forma recursiva 10 veces a `miFunc` y fíjate que cada llamada devuelve `s`. Según tus miedos el programa debería crear 11 objetos de tipo `S`... pero no va a ser así. Esta es la salida del programa:

```
S::S()
S miFunc() [with int R = 0]
S miFunc() [with int R = 1]
S miFunc() [with int R = 2]
S miFunc() [with int R = 3]
S miFunc() [with int R = 4]
S miFunc() [with int R = 5]
S miFunc() [with int R = 6]
S miFunc() [with int R = 7]
S miFunc() [with int R = 8]
S miFunc() [with int R = 9]
S miFunc() [with int R = 10]
int main()
S::~S()
```

Es decir, solo se crea una instancia de S... no 11. Aquí está entrando la [omisión de copia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision), como bien ha comentado @PaperBirdMaster, que como ves no solo se aplica a los contenedores de la STL.

Sin embargo, vamos a ver lo sencillo que es romper este sistema:

```
template<int R>
S miFunc()
{
  S s;
  s = miFunc<R-1>();
  PF;
  return s;
}
```

Con este cambio el resultado de la ejecución cambia considerablemente:

```
S::S()
S::S()
S::S()
S::S()
S::S()
S::S()
S::S()
S::S()
S::S()
S::S()
S::S()
S miFunc() [with int R = 0]
S& S::operator=(S&&)
S::~S()
S miFunc() [with int R = 1]
S& S::operator=(S&&)
S::~S()
S miFunc() [with int R = 2]
S& S::operator=(S&&)
S::~S()
S miFunc() [with int R = 3]
S& S::operator=(S&&)
S::~S()
S miFunc() [with int R = 4]
S& S::operator=(S&&)
S::~S()
S miFunc() [with int R = 5]
S& S::operator=(S&&)
S::~S()
S miFunc() [with int R = 6]
S& S::operator=(S&&)
S::~S()
S miFunc() [with int R = 7]
S& S::operator=(S&&)
S::~S()
S miFunc() [with int R = 8]
S& S::operator=(S&&)
S::~S()
S miFunc() [with int R = 9]
S& S::operator=(S&&)
S::~S()
S miFunc() [with int R = 10]
int main()
S::~S()
```

¿Por qué sucede esto? Bien, lo que hemos hecho con este último cambio es forzar a que en cada llamada a `miFunc` se cree una instancia de `S`, después se copia en esta instancia el estado de la instancia devuelta por el `return` y, claro, como ahora tenemos dos objetos uno de los dos hay que eliminarlo... Aunque esta versión del programa es algo menos óptima que la primera, su ejecución va a seguir siendo bastante más rápida de lo que piensas.

Fíjate que no se está llamando al operador de asignación tradicional sino al de movimiento `S& S::operator=(S&&)`.

Si el objeto retornado admite las operaciones de movimiento y hace uso de memoria dinámica esta operación es prácticamente instantánea ya que el objeto final se *apropia* de los punteros del objeto origen... y copiar punteros es algo prácticamente gratis. En tu caso tienes la suerte de que `std::vector` hace uso de esta característica, luego no deberías preocuparte por este tipo de copias.

Vale, ya vemos que el `return` no debería preocuparnos... ¿Y qué pasa entonces cuando le pasemos este objeto a un montón de funciones?

Está claro que si le pasamos una copia el rendimiento se va a resentir. ¿Qué tal si usamos referencias?

```
struct S
{
    S() { PF; }
    S(const S &) { PF; }
    S(S &&) { PF; }
    S& operator=(S const&) { PF; return *this; }
    S& operator=(S &&) { PF; return *this; }
    ~S() { PF; }

    int value;
};

template<int R>
void refFunc(S & ref)
{
  PF;
  refFunc<R-1>(ref);
}

template<>
void refFunc<0>(S & ref)
{
  ref.value = 1;
  PF;
}

int main()
{
  S s;
  PF;
  refFunc<10>(s);
}
```

Como vemos en el resultado del programa, el número de objetos *copiados* es 0:

```
S::S()
int main()
void refFunc(S&) [with int R = 10]
void refFunc(S&) [with int R = 9]
void refFunc(S&) [with int R = 8]
void refFunc(S&) [with int R = 7]
void refFunc(S&) [with int R = 6]
void refFunc(S&) [with int R = 5]
void refFunc(S&) [with int R = 4]
void refFunc(S&) [with int R = 3]
void refFunc(S&) [with int R = 2]
void refFunc(S&) [with int R = 1]
void refFunc(S&) [with int R = 0]
S::~S()
```

Así que, mi conclusión es que tus argumentos no justifican el uso de punteros inteligentes. No es necesario complicar el código innecesariamente.

Comment: pero mi punto de utilizar los punteros inteligentes es por el uso de excepciones, leyendo sobre las 3 garantías, lo que vi de manera unánime es el uso de punteros inteligentes para evitar la fuga de memoria en caso de una excepción inesperada, lo que entendí fue que las variables automáticas se les llama su respectivo destructor al salir del ámbito, cosa que no sucede con un puntero en bruto, y funcionalidad que le da los punteros inteligentes que gestionan la memoria de esta manera. ¿Existe otra manera de evitar fugas de memoria en esos casos?

Comment: @Mario Si no usas memoria dinámica no puede haber fugas. Si no usas `new` no estás usando memoria dinámica y, por tanto, no puede haber fugas de memoria

Comment: @Mario lo que te propone mi respuesta es no usar punteros ya que hasta donde llego no es necesario el uso de punteros en tu programa

Answer (score 5):

Que respuesta mas corta va a ser esta: **si**, lo estás usando bien :-)

La principal diferencia entre un `std::shared_ptr< >` y un `std::unique_ptr< >` es muy simple: el primero **se puede copiar**; el segundo, **no se puede copiar**.

De ahí la diferencia en el nombre:

- `std::shared_ptr< >`: puntero **compartido**. Varias instancias pueden apuntar a un mismo objeto *físico*, copiandose entre ellas. El `deleter` no se llama **hasta que la última instancia del `std::shared_ptr< >` se destruye**.

  ```
  struct Datos { };

  auto sptr1 = make_shared< Datos >( );
  auto sptr2 = uptr1; // OK.
  ```
- `std::unique_ptr< >`: puntero **único**. Solo una instancia puede apuntar a un objeto *físico*. El `deleter` se llama en cuanto se destruye la única instancia del `std::unique_ptr< >` que puede existir.

  ```
  struct Datos { };

  std::unique_ptr< Datos > uptr1{ new Datos };
  std::unique_ptr< Datos > uptr2 = uptr1; // ERROR
  ```

Ambos tipos se pueden retornar por copia perfectamente; de hecho, es **la forma correcta** de hacerlo:

```
return make_shared< Datos >( );

return std::unique_ptr< Datos >{ new Datos };
```

Si es compilador es *bobo*, en ambos casos llamará al *move-copy-constructor* para retornar el valor; y, si es algo mas *inteligente* (y las circunstancias lo permiten) realizará una [`copy elision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), con lo que llamará directamente al *constructor*, ahorrándose las llamadas al *move-copy-constructor* y las operaciones de movimento implicadas.

Comment: No es necesario el uso de `&&` en el caso de `unique_ptr` (pruébalo con el segundo ejemplo)

Comment: Cierto, llevas razón, como siempre. A ver su pruebo las cosas antes de publicarlas :-(

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Basta con solo retornar `unique_ptr` por valor?

¿Por qué no lo comprobamos? Vamos a usar un objeto chivato que nos hable de su vida:

```
#define PF std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

struct S
{
    S() { PF; }
    S(const S &) { PF; }
    S(S &&) { PF; }
};
```

El objeto `S` nos mostrará un mensaje cuando se construya (`S()`) copie (`S(const S &)`) o mueva (`S(S &&)`). Vamos a ver cómo se comporta cuando lo devolvemos como un valor desde una función:

```
S directo() { return {}; }
S retorno() { S s; return s; }

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Directo\n";
    auto a = directo();
    std::cout << "Retorno\n";
    auto b = retorno();
    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra la salida:

> ```
> Directo
> S::S()
> Retorno
> S::S()
> ```

Vemos una sola construcción en ambos casos, pero ¿qué pasa si desactivamos<sup>2</sup> del compilador la optimización del valor de retorno<sup>1</sup>? La salida cambia así:

> ```
> Directo
> S::S()
> Retorno
> S::S()
> S::S(S&&)
> ```

Vemos que en el primer caso, se ha construido una instancia de `S` una sola vez, y en el segundo caso se ha construido y movido. Ahora veamos lo mismo con punteros inteligentes con optimizaciones:

```
using Sp = std::unique_ptr<S>;

Sp SP_directo() { return std::make_unique<S>(); }
Sp SP_retorno() { auto s = std::make_unique<S>(); return s; }

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Directo\n";
    auto a = SP_directo();
    std::cout << "Retorno\n";
    auto b = SP_retorno();
    return 0;
}
```

La salida es:

> ```
> Directo
> S::S()
> Retorno
> S::S()
> ```

Es decir: una sola construcción del objeto. Desactivando la optimización del valor de retorno<sup>1</sup> la salida es:

> ```
> Directo
> S::S()
> Retorno
> S::S()
> ```

¡La misma! Por lo tanto, a tu pregunta de *¿Basta con solo retornar `unique_ptr` por valor?* la respuesta es: **Si**. Puedes ver este ejemplo de código en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Mkm0mxkE9UblMtAB).

---

1. [Omisión de copia en wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision).
2. Con la opción `-fno-elide-constructors` en gcc.